# Ecto: dynamic fragment from runtime values

Tags: postgresql, elixir, ecto

I'm building an API that allows the end-user to specify the sort on a list of data, returning paginated results. For example,  an API request might specify a sort of `name: :asc, id: :asc`, or `age: :desc, id: :desc`. In the implementation, I'm trying to use the [row-value syntax](https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results/fetch-next-page) for selecting subsequent pages from an existing Ecto query.

In Rails, this is easy — just interpolate a string and splat some arguments:

```rb
# @param [ActiveRecord::Relation] rel
def slice_query(rel, cursor_params)
  # A little hand-waving
  operator, comparisons = parse_params(cursor_params)
  # Suppose `operator` is `<` and comparisons looks like `{name: "Last Row Value", id: "last-row-value"}
  fragment = "(#{comparisons.keys.join(',')}) #{operator} (#{comparisons.size.times.map { '?' }.join(',')})"
  # fragment in this case should look like "(name, id) < (?, ?)"
  rel.where(fragment, *comparisons.values)
end
```

As an Ecto/Elixir newbie, I'm at a loss for how to do this with Ecto. The docs seem to indicate that custom fragments can be implemented via macros, but I'm at a loss for how to dynamically interpolate runtime values into a macro-based implementation.

I've tried something like this:

```
def slice_query(query, cursor_params)
  # More hand-waving; `parse_params` is a bit of pseudocode.
  # Full source is below
  {operator, comparisons} = parse_params(cursor_params)
  query |> where(row_value_comparison(operator, comparisons)
end
```

In particular, `operator` is a binary string, and `comparisons` is the result of an `Enum.map`.

Using [`row_value_comparison` from here](https://elixirforum.com/t/building-an-ecto-macro-to-generate-a-row-value/19680/4?u=feifan), but I've run into various compiler complaints depending on how I interpolate (or don't interpolate) `operator` and `comparisons` into that macro invocation:

- `query |> where(row_value_comparison(operator, comparisons)` yields `protocol Enumerable not implemented for {:comparisons, [line: 114], nil}`
- `query |> where(row_value_comparison(operator, ^comparisons)` yields `protocol Enumerable not implemented for {:^, [line: 114], [{:comparisons, [line: 114], nil}]}`
- `query |> where(row_value_comparison(operator, unquote(comparisons)))` yields `variable "comparisons" does not exist and is being expanded to "comparisons()", please use parentheses to remove the ambiguity or change the variable name`
- `query |> where(row_value_comparison(comparator, unquote(^comparisons)))` yields `cannot use ^comparisons outside of match clauses`

---

Full module source, as requested in comments:

```
defmodule MyProject.Resolvers.Connection do
  import Ecto.Query
  alias MyProject.Repo

  # `cursor_params` should be a Map containing either
  # :after (and optionally :first) (to paginate forward), or
  # :before (and optionally :last) (to paginate backwards).
  # :after or :before should be parsed Cursors.
  #
  # This method implements ApplyCursorsToEdges according to the spec:
  # https://facebook.github.io/relay/graphql/connections.htm#sec-Arguments
  def paginate_with_results(query, cursor_params) do
    total_count = query_count(query)
    query = slice_query(query, cursor_params)
    {has_previous_page, has_next_page} = query_page_info(query, cursor_params)
    query = limit_results(query, cursor_params)

    %{
      results: Repo.all(query),
      page_info: %{
        total_count: total_count,
        has_next_page: has_next_page,
        has_previous_page: has_previous_page
      }
    }
  end

  defp order_bys(query) do
    query.order_bys
    |> Enum.map(fn %Ecto.Query.QueryExpr{expr: expr} ->
      expr
      |> Enum.map(fn {dir, ast} ->
        {dir,
         ast
         |> Macro.expand(__ENV__)
         |> Macro.to_string()
         |> String.replace_prefix("&0.", "")
         |> String.replace_suffix("()", "")
         |> String.to_atom()}
      end)
    end)
    |> List.first()
  end

  defp single_sort_direction?(query) do
    directions = order_bys(query) |> Enum.map(fn {dir, _} -> dir end) |> Enum.uniq()
    if Enum.count(directions) == 1, do: Enum.at(directions, 0), else: false
  end

  defp query_count(query) do
    query |> select([x], count(x.id)) |> Repo.one()
  end

  # https://elixirforum.com/t/building-an-ecto-macro-to-generate-a-row-value/19680/2
  defmacro row_value_comparison(operation, comparisons) do
    # when is_binary(operation) and is_list(comparisons) do
    question_marks = Enum.map(comparisons, fn _ -> "?" end) |> Enum.join(", ")
    frag_text = "(#{question_marks}) #{operation} (#{question_marks})"

    frag_arguments =
      comparisons
      |> Enum.unzip()
      |> Tuple.to_list()
      |> List.flatten()

    quote do
      fragment(unquote(frag_text), unquote_splicing(frag_arguments))
    end
  end

  defp slice_query(query, cursor_params) do
    sort_descriptors = order_bys(query)

    query =
      if Map.has_key?(cursor_params, :after) do
        after_cursor = cursor_params.after

        if direction = single_sort_direction?(query) do
          comparator = if direction == :asc, do: ">", else: "<"

          comparisons =
            Enum.map(sort_descriptors, fn {_dir, field} ->
              {field, after_cursor.sort_values[field]}
            end)

          query |> where(row_value_comparison(comparator, unquote(comparisons)))
        else
          # TODO: Handle multi-direction sort
          query
        end
      end
    # Etc
  end
end
```

Comment: Please post “various compiler complaints” here. We cannot read compiler’s mind.

Comment: Also, `operator, comparisons = ...` is not a valid Elixir match.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin syntax fixed; that was just my mistake here simplifying my actual code. Also added details of the compiler errors I'm seeing. Thank you!

Comment: Show also either the `parse_params` or the content of `comparisons`.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin sure, I've added all the relevant code from the module. `parse_params` was a bit of pseudo-code. Thanks again!